# Настройка bind9

Tags: dns, bind9

Здравствуйте, такая проблема. Пытаюсь создать конфигурацию в bind9 для домена olol.com. Нужно отдавать ип адрес. Я создал подобную конфигурацию, но ответа нету. В чем может быть проблема? Выполнил в терминале  named-checkzone named.local db11.local, ответ - OK
[image: Конфигурация домена]

Comment: А в named.conf вы зону то прописали ? И вообще named запущен ? если ответа вообще нет то может named как таковой не запущен и ни на что не отвечает

Comment: named.conf в нем все пропасино. Как понять замущен лы named? Можете это уточнить. Может мне вообще строку NS удалить ибо мне ip отдать надо?